# Is it possible to create Siebel inound web service based on workflow with more than one operation?

Tags: web-services, siebel

I have a requirement to publish Siebel inbound web service with only one port, at the same time WS has to receive three different operations.
My WS's are based on workflow.
As I could read in the bookshelf the only one operation is possible to add in the one port of WS based on WF:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/CRMWeb/CRMWeb_Overview12.html
(see p.5)
However I've found vanilla WS that looks as I need:
FinancialAssetService

Could anyone give me some tips how to create such WS?
Is it possible to receive different IO by different operations of this WS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your web service provides 3 operations, you must be invoking 3 different workflows, right? (It says so in the page you linked: *a workflow corresponds to a single Web service operation*). Then, yes, you'll need to define 3 "service ports" in your web service.

However, I don't see why that would be a problem at all. I've never done this myself, but you can define the same endpoint URL and HTTP port for each one of the 3 service ports. The external application consuming your service would never notice any difference.

As for your second question, yes, having 3 different workflows would obviously allow you to choose different integration objects for each operation.

---

On the other hand, if you only have one workflow and need 3 operations because you want it to accept different input structures, then you might want to rethink your solution. Perhaps create 3 tiny workflows (or a BS with 3 operations) to just transform the data to a common IO (using Siebel data mappings), and then pass it to your existing WF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @AJPerez!

You're right - I developed 3 different workflows and defined 3 "service ports" in my web service. The reason why I need to use WS having only one operation - that was restriction of the external app: It couldnt make requests to WS with more then one operation. At present external app was improved and there is no anymore those restriction.
Nevertheless thank you a lot for your suggestions!